# Syntax error on 'else' and can't figure out the issue

Tags: python, if-statement

I started Python yesterday and practiced making small scripts but none of them end up working. I somewhat get the basics but I just feel so stupid and frustrated. Here's one of the scripts.

```
UserInput = input("Enter")
if UserInput == "yes":
print ("good job")
elif  print ("wrong"):
else:
   return
```

Comment: is your posted code correct here? The indentation is wrong and indentation matters in python

Comment: where is a conditional for "elif"?

Comment: `elif` is used to check another condition, `else` is used _once_ at the end of a statement as a default.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 problems with the code. The first one is proper indentation. If your code doesn't look like below, use [tab]* to fix it. For the other problems see comments in the code:

```
UserInput = input("Enter")
if UserInput == "yes":
    print ("good job")
# elif requires a condition to evaluate. It's a shorthand for else if 
# you can do e.g. elif UserInput == "no"
elif (condition): # colon goes here
    print ("wrong")
else:
    return
```

Programming requires precise syntax. When you start programming, identifying these small nuisances is difficult. Keep trying. It will become automatic.

*actually you should use 4 spaces, see comment below by Matthias. I personally have my IDE configured to insert 4 spaces when I press [tab].

Comment: The indentation should be made with spaces, not with tabs (see [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Answer (score 0):

this should help. I didn't exactly get what you wanted to do with the elif part , so in this code if and only if the input is yes then it will execute the if condition , otherwise would always execute the else condition.

P.S. :- It would be good if you can clarify what exactly you want .

```
UserInput = raw_input("Enter :- ")
if UserInput == "yes":
    print ("good job")
else:
    print ("wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

`elif` must specify a condition and indentation must be consistent throughout the module:

```
UserInput = input("Enter")
if UserInput == "yes":  
    print ("good job")  # <-+
elif True or False:     #   |   elif needs a condition as well
    print ("wrong"):    # <-+-- indentation must be indentical
else:                   #   |
    return              # <-+
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your indentation

```
UserInput = input("Enter")
if UserInput == "yes":
  print ("good job") 
else:
   print ("wrong")
   return
```

Comment: That `elif` condition strikes me as missing!

Comment: Your code is not valid python: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`